Swap/Bond basis: Bond rates "too high" or swap rates "too low"?
I suppose this question is more of a discussion piece than a question per se, so I apologize in advance.
I've long been fascinated by the large negative basis between government bonds and swaps. These rates shouldn't be different as they are intrinsically linked and there is in theory a way to earn an arbitrage between them. At least in the text-book world, but oh well, frictions and reality.
The question i however keep pondering over, is the following: Is the government bond rate, or the swap rate, more likely to be a better predictor of "true" forward short term rates?
Asked more contrived: Suppose your life depended on predicting what the prevailing 1Y interest rate will be in 20 years. Is the government bond or the swap curve most likely to be an unbiased predictor, or is the truth somewhere in between?

I know swap curves are sometimes considered "purer", but there is compelling evidence that swap rates have a negative bias. A BIS paper shows that negative swap spreads are correlated with the degree of underfunding in pension schemes. Put differently, when pension funds hedge long term liabilities, and simultaneously are strapped for cash, they develop a natural preference for the swap market due to the inherent leverage.
In a more generalized fashion, there seems to be a trend in
financial markets that products/derivatives with built in leverage
tend to trade at a premium compared to the underlying cash market
equivalents for presumably not too dissimilar reasons, which surely
cannot be driven by market fundamentals.
There is compelling reason to believe that long term government bonds have a "premium" built into the yield and hence a positive bias, due to persistently large issue volumes saturating the market as of late, and dealer banks balance sheet constraints imposed post 2008.

So are government bond rates "too high", or are swap rates "too low"? and can we even truly know this?

Just a few comments from me. I'd say just by their very nature and finite 'types' government bonds would be a less efficient estimator of long term market rates. At the short end I'd say swaps and futures (fed funds / sofrs) are quite efficient at pricing these ever changing rates. But towards the longer end of the curve there are so many issues such as convexity, risk premia, bond specific richness /cheapness, future contract eligibility that it becomes almost moot to consider what 20y1y fwd is for example (some of the preceding point apply to both bonds and swaps).

And what's more problematic in using these rates to deduce long term expectations of short rates is that these factors are correlated to business cycles, risk aversion and are far from constant.

Thank you very much, that's a very helpful and meaningful explanation. I realize there is little practical value in my question, but I thank you none-the-less.

I would argue that gov bonds and IR swaps are not representing the same kinds of risk and hence their levels may differ.

They are not at all the same. They have different credit quality in them. They are different markets!  In the time of LIBOR, swaps were seen as “AA-self-repleneshing credit”. Govvies are AAA and far more liquid. That said swap spreads can also be negative as in uk gilts.

@NBF. Would you mind elaborating on this points please?
These days, benchmark swap rates reference risk free rates, traded at central counterparties, collateralized and margined to near eliminate counterparty risk, often backed by that very same government bond collateral. Although clearly swaps can never be as good a credit than the government itself. So if anything, swaps, like in the old Libor days, should trade at a tiny but positive premium to government bonds purely from a credit risk perspective. But swap spreads are massively negative in the US and UK: the other way around.

Negative swaps spreads are to do with balance sheet. 0 to do with credit risk these days imo.

First - a lot of thing that seem the same are not and never were. Futures with convexity adj are not swaps even when you adjust for daycounts etc. Some traders will fit futures curves and swap curves and (they used to) trade the convexity. Swaps and Bonds are very different markets. First liquidity wise - Futures >> ONTRs >> Olds ~ Swaps. Swaps are a closed market between counterparties with ISDAs. Swaps are daily margined but may still have counterparty credit risk. You can't just get out of swap - you have to novate or assign it. It's a much smaller market as a consequence. Treasuries - you or I can buy them. No isda, no mra, no nothing. Sure, repo is harder. Also US Treasury repo is probably the best funding in the world, esp when they are on special, with very small haircuts (depending on the vol).
And, you're correct - swaps used to be LIBOR>>Treasury Funding (e.g., GC or special repo), when the Treasury spread was a proxy for public-private credit spreads. Nowadays, this component is gone in USD.  (Side note, we used to think swap spreads could not go negative in the UK...this was clearly wrong).
Regardless, there is no abstract 'forward' rate as you originally brought up. It's nice to think about it and the books present it that way, but it never was true. We used to put 3m, 6m, 12m Cash LIBOR + 3M Futures + Swaps on the same curve. In retrospect, it was dumb. If you can't trade them the same you are making a great presumption by trying to treat them the same. Moreover, there is no risk-free rate--there are hundreds of short-rates and traders trade STIR and knowing the plumbing can be a source of income. I am not an expert in this area (I know a bunch of STIR traders and they know far more about the nuances).
One final thing - no forward rate is a good predictor. Bonds (and swaps) have a term premium in them. I believe it was Fama-Bliss who did the interest-rate premium paper in 1987. It fluctuates much more than expectations do. Oftentimes the best predictor of rates in the futures is rates today (i.e., RW hypothesis).

How do swaps have credit risk ? Swaps are 99% cleared (unless youre talking about bilateral stuff), LCH, CME and EUREX are core infrastructure for the world. To think even if these institutions are totally devoid of resources and not topped up by central banks..is a bit academic

Cleared swaps clearly don't have much in the way of credit risk. (and yes, one can argue that CCHs are seriously concentrated, in fact, systematic sources of risk, but as you say, politics will mean CBs step in).
Swaps are definitely a smaller market than bonds - 112 members of LCH, 28 members (for OTC IRS) at CME, etc. The collateral requirements are prohibitive for most smaller firms. Swaps are much less liquid than Treasuries, and probably even less than most off-the-runs.

I get your point, however I am not sure thr quantum of difference is as you are making it sound. Sure 112 members, the member banks have thousands of clients whom they are clearing trades for as well. I would also point out, leverage in the bond market is via repo, which requires set up and is fairly infra heavy.
